# Abnormal Event Detection in Videos using Spatiotemporal Autoencoder using Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm, autoencoder

I`m trying to improve the accuracy (AUC) of abnormal event detection model i have implemented according to this research paper (*https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01546*) using keras library. the data used is the famous **UCSDped1** only.
the model AUC was at first 50% , after removing **batch normalization** between **COnvLSTM** layers the AUC become 63%, and after many tries with different losses and optimizer and changing parameters , nothing seems to increase it.
I doubt the problem is that the model doesn't do temporal learning right.

The way i understand the model is as follows : during the training phase the result will be the weights learned, and using those weights the frames that have high reconstruction error (original frame - reconstructed frame) will be considered abnormal.
the loss during the training phase is about 0.0013.
so what could be wrong?

any feedback would be very appreciated.

here's the code:

```
model = Sequential()

#2 convolution layers
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(128, 11, 11 , border_mode='valid',activation = 'tanh', subsample = (4,4)), input_shape=(None,227, 227, 1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='valid',activation = 'tanh', subsample = (2,2))))
#3 ConvLSTM layers
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(nb_filter=64, nb_row=3, nb_col=3,
                   border_mode='same', return_sequences=True))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(nb_filter=32, nb_row=3, nb_col=3,
                   border_mode='same', return_sequences=True))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(nb_filter=64, nb_row=3, nb_col=3,
                   border_mode='same', return_sequences=True))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
#2 Deconvolution layers
model.add(TimeDistributed(Deconvolution2D(128, 5, 5,border_mode='valid',activation = 'tanh', output_shape=(None,55, 55, 128), subsample = (2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Deconvolution2D(1, 11, 11,border_mode='valid',activation = 'tanh', output_shape=(None,227, 227, 1), subsample = (4,4))))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(train_data,train_data, batch_size=64,nb_epoch=10)
reconstructed = model.predict(test_data)

e = (test_data-reconstructed)**2

ex = []
for i in e:
    ex.append(np.sqrt(np.sum(i)))

e_min = min(ex)
e_max = max(ex)
abnormality_score = (ex-e_min)/(e_max-e_min)

from sklearn import metrics
#y_test contains 1's for abnormal frame and 0's for normal frame 
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, abnormality_score )
roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)

print fpr,tpr,thresholds

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'b', label = 'AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Training `LSTM` for 10 epochs is not the best idea. Even if it's `ConvLstm`. Try many more epochs first

Comment: I have trained the model before with 35 and with 45 epoch , but the AUC doesn't change remains at 63%.

Comment: By bigger number of epochs I mean a few K, not 50

Comment: what do you mean by 'K' ?

Comment: Thousands / Kilos

Comment: Wow, i wonder if that number can even run on floydhub gpu! , but the research paper said they made training with maximum number of epochs = 50.